# How do i solve this load method issue in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, ads

I'm new to flutter. I've added the Googole_mobile_ads package to my flutter app and I'm having a hard time solving this error [erroe message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11qvf.jpg).
it says

**The method 'load' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: load()**

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  final String ek;
  final String eek;
  final String eeek;
  final String eeeek;
  final String eeeeek;

  Page(this.ek, this.eek, this.eeek, this.eeeek, this.eeeeek);

  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
// here
  BannerAd banner;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final adState = Provider.of<AdState>(context);

    // final AdWidget adWidget = AdWidget(ad: banner);

    adState.initialization.then((status) {
      setState(() {
        banner = BannerAd(
          size: AdSize.banner,
          adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
          request: AdRequest(),
          listener: BannerAdListener(),
        )..load();
        banner.load();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            child: AdWidget(
              ad: banner..load(),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: share some code and your error here.

Comment: @zeia soroush hii, just edited the question, plz check

Comment: did you add this  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize(); to your code? and i think you need to await  for adState.initialization. did you read their documentation? https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

Comment: yeah, i did add WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); MobileAds.instance.initialize(); to my code. and where exactly should i use await method?

Comment: Do this way void didChangeDependencies() { .... await adState.initialization......

Comment: I will write the entire working code as soon as posible for you. If my comments could not help

Comment: yes, please. I have tried adding await but it doesn't seem to work. i'm just getting more complicated errors that i don't understand . i will waiting for you for the solution. thanks mannn

Answer (score 1):

this is a working code with testAdUnit id.
[this is the flutter code](https://gist.github.com/zeiasoroush/b7aafb89fe900af1d2606cb8e8149458)

and as [their documentation said](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter#2)

add this lines to your project androidmanifest.xml for test ads

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>`